# How to get data in a Flutter-ListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-textformfield

I'm building a form for shipping and am able to add as many items as possible. *(Adding a Widget in a ListView every time a button is pressed)*

My question is, once the form widgets are created and filled, **how do I get the information from each TextFormField in each Widget?**
Once the information is retrieved I will send it to Firebase.

Here's the code I Have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login_test/helpers/constants.dart';

class AddItemsToRequest extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddItemsToRequest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddItemsToRequest> createState() => _AddItemsToRequestState();
}

class _AddItemsToRequestState extends State<AddItemsToRequest> {
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
  List<Widget> fields = [];
  RegExp regExp = RegExp('[aA-zZ]');
  int quantity = 0;
  double weight = 0;
  double height = 0;
  
  Widget itemForm() {
  return Column(children: [
    Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(color: grey, border: Border.all(color: black)),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text('Package details',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  backgroundColor: grey,
                  fontSize: 24)),
        )),
    Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: TextFormField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              quantity = value as int;
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty || value is int
                ? 'Quantity cannot be empty'
                : null,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(0.0),
                  ),
                ),
                fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 238, 238),
                filled: true,
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.5),
                ),
                hintText: "Quantity : "),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: TextFormField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              weight = value as double;
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty || regExp.hasMatch(value)
                ? 'Weight cannot be empty'
                : null,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(0.0),
                  ),
                ),
                fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 238, 238),
                filled: true,
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.5),
                ),
                hintText: "Weight : "),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: TextFormField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              height = value;
            },
            validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Height cannot be empty' : null,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(0.0),
                  ),
                ),
                fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 238, 238),
                filled: true,
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.5),
                ),
                hintText: "Height : "),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ]);
}
 

  Widget _addTile() {
    return ElevatedButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          final controller = TextEditingController();
          final field = itemForm();

          setState(() {
            controllers.add(controller);
            fields.add(field);
          });
        });
  }
  Widget _listView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: fields.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = fields[index];
        return Dismissible(
          key: ObjectKey(item),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            // Remove the item from the data source.
            setState(() {
              fields.removeAt(index);
            });
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Package removed')));
          },
          background: Container(
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 210, 31, 19),
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Remove ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 32),
                ),
              )),
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: fields[index],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _okButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        for (var element in fields) {
          print(quantity);
        }
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        print('ok');
      },
      child: const Text("OK"),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: blue),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Flexible(child: _addTile()),
          SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200,
              child: _listView()),
          Flexible(child: _okButton()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting this **answer**. iterate your list of `texteditingcontroller` and get the text stored in that **controllers** one by one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++) {
  var data = controllers[i].text;
  //print or add data to any other list and insert to another list and save to database
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am adding a controller to the Widget itemForm() every time I add a new one, your answer would work if I was adding only a TextFormField. But every widget contains 3 TextFormFields and my problem is that I don't know how to get the text from each.